# git / github unresolved conflicts but no visible differences

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I am using eclipse, git and github. A friend of mine forked my github repo and changed some code. There was a pull request, I accepted the changes to my github repo. Now I tried to commit my own files and I am not able to 'commit and push'. As you can see in my screenshot there are no visible differences in the file. What procedure will solve this conflict? [image]

Comment: Are you pushing directly to `master`?

Comment: possible causes of "invisible conflicts" could be due to different line endings, or changing file permissions. Did you check those?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your friend's work got merged into `master` and you are on branch `your-feature-branch` then:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout your-feature-branch
git rebase master
```

will attempt to rebase your work on top of `master`, which already includes your friend's changes.  The rebase procedure will process your commits one at a time and inform you of any conflicts which you can then resolve.  Each file with conflicts will have conflict markers that tell you the changes introduced by each branch.  After resolving the conflicts stage your changes then do

```
git rebase --continue
```

Repeat until rebase finishes.  If at any point you become confused you can always abandon the rebase with

```
git rebase --abort
```

Once your work is rebased push `your-feature-branch` to origin, open a pull request, then merge.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue sometimes, without a visible reason. Using a git rm on the directory containing the bad file, followed by a git reset --hard solved the issue for me.

```
git rm --cached -r DIRECTORY    
git reset --hard
```